# Finding the Lebesgue Measure

Tags: measure-theory

Prove that the lebesgue measure of A = { (x,y,z) : x=y=z } in R^3 .

I want to prove this by covering A by countably many cubes so that each covering
has measure 0 so that we can use countable additivity to conclude that the measure
of A is 0 .

I can visualise the picture , but cannot write the covering explicitly.

Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 2):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and take boxes centered at $\pm(n,n,n)$ with sides $2$, $\varepsilon2^{-n}$ and $\varepsilon2^{-n}$ with the long axis parallel with $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: I want to cover it by rectangles or cubes only

Comment: Use cubes centered at $(r_n,r_n,r_n)$ of side $2^{-n}\varepsilon$ then.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your idea, @mrf. The equivalent construction in one dimension doesn't cover the whole real line.

Comment: @kahen that's silly of me. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Because Lebesgue measure is invariant under linear isometries, the problem reduces to showing that $R := \{(x,0,0) \in \mathbb R^3 \mathrel\mid x \in \mathbb R\}$ has measure $0$. This is relatively easily done with "cubes that get smaller $y$ and $z$ sides as they get farther away from the origin". This should (relatively easily) produce a countable collection of boxes covering $R$ with measure less than $\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Yes, I know that , but I do not want to use this result.Actually I just want to cover the given line by cubes ,but I mathematically cannot write the cover explicitly which I can easily do for your set.So please give me the mathematical representation of the cover of A